# IO not defined in file but is defined in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I feel really stupid for asking this but I'm trying to load in some extra functionality and in the process making use of an injected JS file. This injected file looks like this:

```
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    script.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(io);
            var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:1200');
            socket.emit('test', 'test');
        }, 5000);
    };

    script.src = 'https://localhost:1200/socket.io/socket.io.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
})();
```

When I refresh my page and take a look at the console the only error message I see is this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` which is strange because when I execute this piece of code:

```
console.log(io);
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:1200');
socket.emit('test', 'test');
```

in the console of Chrome, it just works. Can somebody point out to me what I am doing wrong because I'm starting to really pull my hair out at this point.

Comment: According to [this](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) you may have to check for the `onreadystatechange` before running the onload function?

Comment: Problem is, I also tried jQuery's `#getScript()` function to load in this file dynamically but that also didn't work. I think it has something to do with scopes but can't quite figure out what exactly.